# Removing required from a form element via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that hides and shows option based on a drop down. If one option is selected there is a form that had required fields (). If the other option is selected I need to disable those required fields or the form won't submit.

Long and short. How do I remove the required for the input element via Javascript?

I was trying document.getItemById('firstName').?

Comment: Sorry FINALLY found a hint on Google that worked

`document.getElementById('firstName').removeAttribute('required');`

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById('firstName').removeAttribute('required');